# Detect click outside of element, check if checkbox is checked, and trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(event) { //line 1
        if(!$(event.target).closest('#menu').length) { //line 2
            if($('.menu-btn').is(':checked')) { //line 3
                $('#menu-btn').trigger('click'); //line 4
            }
        }        
    })
})
```

Line 1 works, line 2 works, line 3 doesn't work and it also doesn't allow me to check the checkbox. why is that?

**Edit: here is what I'm trying to do:**

line 1 is to detect if there is a click. line 2 is to detect if the click is outside of the #menu and line 3 is to check if the menu-btn is checked off. if it is checked off, then line 4 will trigger the menu-btn click. the problems is line 3 is not allowing me to check the checkbox if it is currently not checked.

Comment: How many `.menu-btn`s do you have?

Comment: @AdamAzad I just have one

Answer (score 0):

you can use prop to check the checkbox instead of triggering a click event on it as `$('#menu-btn').prop('checked', 'checked');` and uncheck it with `$('#menu-btn').prop('checked', false);`

Toggling code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(event) { //line 1
        if(!$(event.target).closest('#menu').length) { //line 2
            if(!$('#menu-btn').prop('checked')) { //line 3
                $('#menu-btn').prop('checked', 'checked'); //line 4
            } else {
                $('#menu-btn').prop('checked', false);
            }
        }        
    })
})
```

Comment: Yes. if menu-btn is checked, do console.log("test");. but it is not letting me check it

Comment: Change .menu-btn to #menu-btn and check the updated answer

Comment: You are using the operator wrong. `is(':checked')` returns true is the checkbox is checked and false otherwise. You need to have `!` operator before it

Answer (score 0):

Try this toggle code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).click(function() {
        $('#menu-btn').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
<input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
```

Comment: that just removed my line 3 function. i need line 3 but i need it to work.